# Accessing function within another controller in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a function within an AdminController for sending emails. I want to access this within another controller.  Can anyone advise how I would modify this to work?

OrdersController

```
public function postOrder()
{
   $order = New Order;
   ...
   $order->save();
   // email order (call function in other controller)
   $this->emailOrder($order);
}
```

AdminController

```
public function emailOrder($order)
{
//email processing goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would strip it out, either into an abstract controller, that your controllers inherit from:

```
class AdminController extends MyController
```

Or to a service that you can call from your controller:

```
Mail::sendOrder($order)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have set up a helper class to handle this, but it gives me error 'Undefined variable: order'. The service is set up to grab the ($order).

Comment: I take that back, all working well. My method was set to private static instead of just private.  Thank you for your help.